# VB.net String Reverse Property different based on Env

Tags: vb.net

I am debugging an application that runs on a server and users will access the application on another server. The application uses encryption and as part of the key, I am using the `String.Reverse` property.

```
Dim Mystring As String = "123abc"
Dim reverse = String.Format("{0},{1}", Mystring.Reverse)
```

The string `reverse` is different when I run it from one machine (RDP/Citrix Environment ASP.NET 4.6.1). The value is:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>d__a2`1[System.Char]
```

The same string, but ran from another machine (RPD non-Citrix Environment ASP.NET 4.5.2). The value of `reverse` is:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>d__73`1[System.Char]
```

Why are the values different in the different environments?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line first:

```
Dim reverse = String.Format("{0},{1}", Mystring.Reverse)
```

Specifically, this expression:

```
Mystring.Reverse
```

`Reverse` is a function, not a property, but it's missing the parentheses `()`. The trick here is the `String.Format()` method accepts the base `Object` type as an argument, and compiler is able to treat the `MyString.Reverse` expression as a delegate type that is convertible to object. The values you see in your output are the result of calling `.ToString()` on that function delegate. It's the type name for the function, rather than anything to do with the value of your `MyString` object. Since that type is dynamically and randomly generated at runtime, you'll see different values not only on different platforms, but different runs on the same computer.

In the VB6 era, it was normal to call methods without the parentheses. In the .Net world, **always** use parentheses when you call a method.

What you want is this:

```
Dim reverse As String = String.Format("{0},{1}", Mystring.Reverse())
```

Even here, you're missing the second argument to match the format string. I doubt you'll get the result you expect.

Finally, reversing a string as the key seems *very* wrong when it comes to encryption. You are using a real cyrptogrpahic algorithm from the `System.Security.Cryptography` library, right? *Right!?*

Comment: I am taking over someone else's work from a year ago. Honestly, encryption, in general, is new to me. I am trying to piece meal stuff together. I am using the Security.Cryptography library. When I run the application in an ASP.net 4.5.2 environment, the string I am trying to encode works fine. I am using the string.reverse method above and it seems to decrypt just fine. However, the new environment using 4.6.1 and it doesn't seem to decrypt correctly. I am thinking because of the .net version something changed and I can't use the same key.

Comment: I also tried adding `()` to the method. Still gives me the same thing.

Comment: @PeterSun Without meaning to be rude, you are going to get something wrong. Crypto is an extremely complex topic and there is a massive gulf between "works" as in "it compiles and runs" and "is cryptographically strong". If you're in a situation that _requires_ cryptography, get a contractor for a month or two to do the work and teach you the basics. If crypto isn't that important to you, there are easier ways to obfuscate. I've been doing this for years and there's always another edge case or vector you haven't considered. If you're just starting out you're almost guaranteed to miss something

Comment: I created a workaround, but this post is more about curiosity than getting something to work. Is there a good place to start?

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting the value of the reversed `String` but the name of the type used to perform the reversal.  That type is dynamically created and randomly named.  The "d" in those two names means "dynamic" and the "a2" and "73" parts are random.

Basically, what you perceive to be an issue is not an issue.  The problem is that you're not actually creating a `String` from the reversed output.  You say "`String.Reverse` property but that is NOT a property.  It is a method and it is not a member of the `String` class but rather an extension method on the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface.  You are treating your `String` as an enumerable list of `Char` values and reversing that.  If you want a `String` from that then you need to create one, i.e.

```
MyReversedString = New String(Mystring.Reverse().ToArray())
```

That will push the contents of your iterator into an array and then create a new `String` object from that array.